# How to set Max date dynamically for date picker in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, datepicker, maxdate

I have date picker and i want to set maximum date as TODAY date which will change daily.
For ex today's date is 28/6/2011 so maximum date is 28/6/2011 but when i use my app tomorrow it will be change to 29/6/2011.
How to set this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `maximumDate` property in `viewWillAppear:` method like this,

```
datePicker.maximumDate = [NSDate date];
```

To deal with date change while the application is being used, get the time left till tomorrow and set an NSTimer to trigger off at date change and then update the `UIDatePicker` instance.

```
NSDate * tomorrow = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"12 AM tomorrow"];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [tomorrow timeIntervalSinceNow];

/* Create an NSTimer to trigger a method to update the datePicker's maximumDate 
   after timeInterval */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the [`documentation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html) you will see that there is a property of `UIDatePicker` called `maximumDate`. If you then look at the documentation for [`NSDate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDate) you will see that the class method `date` returns an NSDate with the current date and time, therefore:
`someDatePicker.maximumDate = [NSDate date];
will set the date picker to not allow any date (or time) later than that moment.

Answer (score 0):

As [NSDate date] or Date() returns the current today's date.

**In Objective-C**

Set the date picker's minimumDate property:

```
datePicker.minimumDate = [NSDate date];
```

**In Swift 4.x,**

```
datePicker.minimumDate = Date()
```

(Where datePicker is a reference to your UIDatePicker )